# "?" character in the submitted url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I am submitting a form through javascript on click of a button and redirecting it to another url.

The code I am using to submit and redirect it is as follows:

```
function SelectorSubmitOld(targetUrl) {

    var f = jQuery('form').get(0);

    jQuery("#__VIEWSTATE").remove();

    f.action = targetUrl;
    f.submit();
}
```

Frankly speaking this method was developed by some other developer and I do not know what the above method does because of my limited javascript knowledge.

The `targetUrl` which I am passing in this instance is `"/home-loans/interest-rates/"`

But when the processing completes and the final page loads, the url contains a "?". So my final url becomes `"/home-loans/interest-rates/?"`

The "?" is not desirable and I want to get ride of it.

Any ideas?

P.S.: Earlier I had few input fields with the attribute `name` attached to them. Because of this the url was appending the value against this attribute.

So for example if the input was `<input type="text" class="mobile_number" name="mobile-number">` the url use to become `"/home-loans/interest-rates/?mobile-number="`.

But once I removed the name attribute it was fine. However, the "?" still remains.

The back-end is asp.net, just so you should know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: Did you try putting a `debugger;` statement inside function and launch firebug(FF)/Developer Tools(IE/Chrome) to see what is coming in `targetUrl` parameter? Also check in your code behind if any url modifications happening.

Comment: This is because you `form method` is `GET`

Comment: Generally we do form `submit` whenever we need to post the form data (field's data which are inside `<form> </form>`) to the server side code. Here if you have no elements within your form then what you are achieving by posting that empty form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because you submit a form using `GET` method.
You can use `POST` method instead:

```
<form method="POST"></form>
```

However, it looks like you don't want to submit any data with this form.
If I am right, then you can simply use `document.location.href` in order to navigate to another page:

```
document.location.href = targetUrl;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I do something that does not involve changing the function? The reason is the function is used in many places and the button code creation which uses this function is also centralized and used by many pages.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to send any query parameters along with the URL, you could add method="POST" to the form element, something like this

```
jQuery('form').attr('method', 'POST')
```